# How to get a HTML5 audio tag audio to come from receiver instead of speaker?

Tags: iphone, html, audio, speaker

I was trying to do the following on IPhone:

- load a webpage on UIWebView control in my application.
- The webpage has an audio tag (`<audio/>` in HTML5) with source of the audio file set correctly.
- Webpage loads correctly and when I click on play button the audio was coming out from the receiver.

How do I make the audio to come out of the receiver instead of the speaker?

What have I already done?

- I read about the Audio session services on apple platforms.
- My initial category was kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord.
- Now by default, according to the documentation the audio should go to the reciever. 
  The above did not work.
- So I started listening on the kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange property. So when I played audio using the audio tag I got a callback. In the callback I queried for the audio route which came back with a string "RecieverAndMicrophone"

So looks like the browser control is doing some magic to override the app default audio session settings. How do I change that behavior through my app?

Comment: This question would benefit from providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have so far to avoid the community doing any heavy lifting.